# Reverse property path in Turtle RDF serialization?

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf

In the Turtle serialization of an RDF graph, I have many triples like this (many individuals, all with a common value of type):

```
:A a :b .
:B a :b .
:C a :b .
:D a :b .
# …
:Z a :b .
```

Is there any way to write this succinctly in Turtle?  In SPARQL, which has some similarities to Turtle, we can write:

```
:b ^a :A, :B, :C, …, :Z .
```

Is there a counterpart in Turtle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a Turtle shortcut for this.  See [RDF 1.1 Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-turtle-20140225/) One suggestion is to use one of the many free ontology editors and not have to worry much about reading the text serialization.  [TopBraid Composer Free](http://www.topquadrant.com/downloads/topbraid-composer-install/) and [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/) are good choices, though Protégé is more focused on OWL.

Comment: This is one of the frustrating things about Turtle.  The SPARQL query syntax actually *does* have something for this:  the reverse property path.  Using it, we can write `:b ^rdf:type :A, :B, :C, :D`. N3 had something like this, too (but I'm not sure it's exactly the same), but it didn't make it into Turtle, I guess. :(

Comment: Property paths are a "path", meaning it's a way to match graph patterns by specifying a set of triple patterns.  Specifying triples in text representations via Turtle, JSON-LD, RDF/XML, etc are really a different objective.

Comment: Yes, arbitrary paths wouldn't make a lot of sense, because what would the intermediate nodes be?  But a reverse property would be very helpful in cases like these.

Comment: Even though late: Would be helpful, indeed. The intermediate node would have to be blank nodes, of course. This may be undesirable from an engineering perspective, but very nice from a modelling perspective.